# pan / swipe gestures to scroll a textview using code?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have a textview on the view controller. The size of the textview is small so it's hard to put the finger in there and scroll up or down.

[image: viewcontroller]

What I'd really like to do is to hold the finger down and drag up and the view scrolls up, drag down and the view scrolls down.

I'm currently doing it via UISwipeGestureRecognizer (on the view so there's plenty of space) to scroll up about a line for each swipe, which goes something like this:

```
func scrollTextUp() {
    let currentOffset = textView.contentOffset
    let padding : CGFloat = 10
    textView.setContentOffset(
        CGPoint(
            x: currentOffset.x,
            y: currentOffset.y - padding < 0 ? 0 : currentOffset.y - padding
        ),
        animated: true
    )
}
```

I'm thinking that I need a UIPanGestureRecognizer to do the job but how do I detect the action going up or down and ignore all other directions?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does your textview allow editing/selection of text or is it just static text displayed in it?

Comment: Just static text displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion here would be to use touchesMoved and calculate the different between the current position of the touch vs the previous position of the touch. Then you can use that value to change the content offset. Note: you will also want to add protections against allowing the offset to become too small or too large. See a quick example of this below, this was done quickly so there may be better ways to do certain pieces most notably determining the initial offset of the textview, but this should get you going.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let tv = UITextView()
    var originalYOffset: CGFloat = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(tv)
        tv.text = "Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text "
        tv.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        originalYOffset = tv.contentOffset.y
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let currentLocation = touch.location(in: touch.view)
            let previousLocation = touch.previousLocation(in: touch.view)
            let amountMoved = previousLocation.y - currentLocation.y
            let newOffset = min(max(originalYOffset, tv.contentOffset.y + amountMoved), tv.contentSize.height - tv.frame.size.height)

            tv.contentOffset.y = newOffset
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks!! I was thinking that maybe I should use a combo of pan and swipe...this is simple and clean!

Comment: Err....this works perfectly but it seems to have override the longPressGesture?? Can both co-exist?

Comment: Ah, the joys of the responder chain. You may have a hard time with these coexisting because the touches moved method is capturing the touch and not allowing gestures to be received. You may want to try calling Super touches moved but you might also want to try using pan gesture with logic similar to my moved method within. Multiple gestures at a time are going to get pretty difficult quickly and you’re generally better off having gestures added to different views to avoid these types of issues. It may be worth considering design changes as well. Sorry I don’t have better answers on this one.

Comment: yeah..that's what I thought..the touches will take precedence over the long press. I'll try the pan gesture now that you've given me an idea how to detect up and down. Thanks.

Comment: Nope, pan gesture doesn't work...same problem. I guess I'll have to think of another way. Thanks.

Comment: You could start thinking of ways to differentiate the gestures. You could use the number of touches for example as a way to do this. Maybe two touches for the pan.

Comment: OK, egg on face. It turns out I changed something and broke my code for the longPressGesture. This code and longPressGesture co-exists perfectly. I don't have enough reputation to move this to chat. Sorry. Thanks for all your help and suggestions.